# Google Firestore Prevent User Profile Update from duplicating a username & email of another user

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I currently am working on a cloud function that will allow a user to update their profile.  They can update the contents of their user document and this is currently working no issue.  The thing I want to prevent; however, is a user being able to update their username or email to one that is currently being used by another user.  The current issue is if a user updates their email to one that already exists in my database, the users accounts become linked.  How do I cut off the request so that a user cannot change their email or username to one that already exists

```
exports.profileUpdate = (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.email) {
    admin.auth().updateUser(req.user.uid, { email: req.body.email })
  }

  let document = db
    .collection('users')
    .where('username', '==', req.user.username)
  document
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.id
        db.collection('users').doc(data).update(req.body)
      })
      res.json({ message: 'Updated Successfully' })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Cannot Update the value'
      })
    })
}
```

when i try to prevent update of username/email:

```
exports.profileUpdate = async (req, res) => {
  let gate
  let docId
  let params
  if (req.user.email) {
    admin.auth().updateUser(req.user.uid, { email: req.body.email })
  }

  let document = db
    .collection('users')
    .where('username', '==', req.body.username)

  const updateProfile = (doc, body) => {
    db.collection('users').doc(doc).update(body)
    return res.json({ message: 'Updated Successfully' })
  }

  await document
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        gate = true
      } else {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = doc.data()
          if (data.userId == req.body.userId) {
            gate = true
            docId = doc.id
            params = req.body
          } else {
            gate = false
          }
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Cannot Update the value'
      })
    })

  // return console.log(gate, '->', docId, '/', params)
  return gate ? updateProfile(docId, params) : console.log('shouldn't update')
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  You're going to have to check to see if the username already exists.  It looks like you're doing a query for that, so all you have to do is check the results of the query and enforce the condition you stated.

Comment: I would like a user to only be able to update their profile to a username that is unique and to an email that is unique.  if an email or username is already taken by a user, I would like to prevent the request from going through.

Comment: OK, what's wrong with the code you've written now?  If you're asking someone to write the logic for this requirement, that's not really how Stack Overflow works.  It's expected that you make an attempt, then post the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: the issue with the code is that it updates the user values for email and username even if it exists in my database, so if a user updates their email to an already existing one it links those accounts.  understood just looking for direction

Comment: have you tried something to enforce this behavior of not updating if the username of email already exist? if yes could you share what have you tried for this?

Comment: @JoséSoní the issue now is creating a username that doesn't already exist and updating an email with a value that doesn't already exist

Comment: could you share the data structure you are using please?

Comment: I was able to figure out a solution making a check for the username's in use and if there was a duplicate found in the snapshot throw a 400 and prevent the cloud function from running @Jose Soni

Comment: could you publish your solution as an aswer, It can help other users facing the same issue

Comment: published the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the answer using the following, probably not the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done for my use case nonetheless:

here is my profile update cloud function:

```
exports.profileUpdate = async (req, res) => {
  let userDetails = req.body
  const { valid } = await reduceUserDetails(userDetails)

  if (!valid) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Already In Use' })
  } else {
    let document = db.collection('users').where('userId', '==', req.user.userId)
    document
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = doc.id
          db.collection('users').doc(data).update(req.body)
          if (req.body.email) {
            admin.auth().updateUser(req.user.userId, {
              email: req.body.email
            })
          }
        })
        res.json({ message: 'Updated Successfully' })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: 'Cannot Update the value'
        })
      })
  }
}
```

and here is the reduceUserDetails function that performs the check for a unique username as well as a unique email:

```
const { admin, db } = require('./admin')

exports.reduceUserDetails = data => {
  let errors = {}
  if (data.username) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let errors = {}
      const userRef = db
        .collection('users')
        .where('username', '==', data.username)

      userRef
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          if (!snapshot.empty) {
            errors.username = 'username taken'
            resolve({ valid: false, errors: errors })
          } else {
            resolve({ valid: true, errors: errors }) //console.log('im not taken')
          }
        })
        .catch(() => resolve({ result: false, errors: errors }))
    })
  } else if (data.email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let errors = {}
      const userRef = db.collection('users').where('email', '==', data.email)

      userRef
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          if (!snapshot.empty) {
            resolve({ valid: false, errors: errors })
          } else {
            resolve({ valid: true, errors: errors }) //console.log('im not taken')
          }
        })
        .catch(() => resolve({ result: false, errors: errors }))
    })
  } else {
    return {
      errors,
      valid: Object.keys(errors).length === 0 ? true : false
    }
  }
}
```